# I want to Dynamic display Database values as test in JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm try to create a menu(Department/categories). now i have a list of buttons in grid Layout. When the page get loaded i want all of those button to have text name based on the value that i have on the database

I try to do it but it display only the first item on my database in all the button. All my button have a variable name start with menu_dept...

```
import Admin.MySqlConnect;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class POS extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    Connection Conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst= null;
    ResultSet rs= null; 


    /**
     * Creates new form POS
     */
    public POS() {
        initComponents();
        Conn = MySqlConnect.ConnectDB();
        dept_menu();
    }

    public void close(){
        WindowEvent winClosingEvent= new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);

    }
 private void dept_menu(){

    try{


        String Sql="SELECT `dept_name` FROM `department` WHERE 1 " ;
        pst=Conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
        String Add1 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept1.setText(Add1);
        String Add2 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept2.setText(Add2);
        String Add3 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept3.setText(Add3);
        String Add4 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept4.setText(Add4);
        String Add5 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept5.setText(Add5);
        String Add6 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept6.setText(Add6);
        String Add7 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept7.setText(Add7);
         String Add8 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept8.setText(Add8);
        String Add9 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept9.setText(Add9);
        String Add10 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept10.setText(Add10);
         String Add11 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept11.setText(Add11);
        String Add12 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept12.setText(Add12);
        String Add13 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept13.setText(Add13);
         String Add14 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept14.setText(Add14);
        String Add15 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept15.setText(Add15);
        String Add16 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept16.setText(Add16);
         String Add17 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept17.setText(Add17);
         String Add18 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept18.setText(Add18);
         String Add19 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept19.setText(Add19);
         String Add20 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept20.setText(Add20);
         String Add21 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept21.setText(Add21);
         String Add22 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept22.setText(Add22);
         String Add23 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept23.setText(Add23);
         String Add24 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept24.setText(Add24);
         String Add25 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept25.setText(Add25);
         String Add26 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept26.setText(Add26);
         String Add27 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept27.setText(Add27);
         String Add28 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept28.setText(Add28);
         String Add29 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept29.setText(Add29);
         String Add30 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept30.setText(Add30);
        String Add31 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept31.setText(Add31);
        String Add32 = rs.getString("dept_name");
        menu_dept32.setText(Add32);



        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Department found");
        }

        // rs=pst.executeQuery();

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
    finally{
        try{
      rs.close();
      pst.close();
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    }
 }
```

[this is what am getting instead of each button have a different Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zQGW.png)

Comment: Its printing the same name because your using the same name from the result set. You never iterate to the next set. If you want them to have different values you have to call rs.next() to get the next result value.

Comment: I have, if you look at my if statement(if(rs.next()){.....}

Comment: Or can you show me the correct way of using rs.next(), maybe that is the problem

Comment: Left a post instead of trying to explain in a comment. That should hopefully work. P.S. sorry the response took so long

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your only ever getting the first value from your rs (rs.getString("dept_name");) so it is only ever getting the current string value from the of the designated column in the current row (From the java doc).

you need a way of iterating over the result set so that you move onto the next row's so that you dont set the same value to the different add strings.

You should instead of doing if(rs.next()) you should do while(rs.next), so something like this should work:

```
      //Move your menu depts to some sort of iterable list/map e.g.
  Map<Integer, Object> menuDeptIdMap = new HashMap<>();
  menuDeptIdMap.put(1, menu_dept1);
  menuDeptIdMap.put(2, menu_dept2);
  menuDeptIdMap.put(3, menu_dept3);

  String Sql = "SELECT `dept_name` FROM `department` WHERE 1 ";
  pst = Conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
  rs = pst.executeQuery();

  int index = 0;

  while (rs.next())
  {
    index++;
    String deptName = rs.getString("dept_name");
    menu_dept = menuDeptIdMap.get(index);
    menu_dept.setText(deptName);
  }
```

Let me know if that helped :)